# After 48 hours, CPU not reset

Tags: cpu

Looking at https://eosweb.net the CPU is still exhausted (solid green line).

Does it have anything to do with token transfers ?
Why doesn't it reset ?

EDIT2: Reading the technical papers, there is no clear definition. Some sentences mention 3 days, other 6 months. Understanding it in clear terms might need an interpreter.
https://steemit.com/eos/@eosio/eos-io-technical-white-paper

EDIT3: Some wallets still register it as staked, so it is most likely that the usage was too high and that it will take more time to be reset.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How long is the reset period of the cpu bandwith?](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/912/how-long-is-the-reset-period-of-the-cpu-bandwith)

Comment: Accepted answer from the link does not answer the question, since they said 24hr.

Comment: To everyone saying their CPU / NET hasn't reset, you must complete a NEW transaction for your % to show accurately again. Think that the cache of the value only clears when a transaction happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re CPU/NET recharging:

> The 3 day period you mentioned is, used for calculating the
>   exponential moving average and not the repletion period.
>
> The variable account_cpu_usage_average_window_ms represents the 24
>   hour period in milliseconds. This when divided by the block interval
>   (500ms) gives number of slots in 24 hour period, represented by the
>   variable account_cpu_usage_average_window
>
> This value is later used as the window size. So I understand the
>   repletion period as 24 hours. I haven't checked any of these things in
>   any wallets, so I recommend it before making decisions based on code
>   alone.

[How Does NET/CPU Recharge Over Time?](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1403/how-does-net-cpu-recharge-over-time/1421?noredirect=1#comment1189_1421)

Answer (score 1):

CPU resources is the average over one day. The used CPU is continously restored of one day.

If that is not reflected on a website then this is probably a caching issue or so of that site.

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER:

According to online wallets such as eosflare.io the return happened the same time a transaction (unstaking) happened.  It could mean that some activity needs to happen first in order to see the CPU reset. Otherwise, I really cannot explain why or how...