# How Does NET/CPU Recharge Over Time?

Tags: resources, cpu, net

I'm asking this because [**no one**](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/912/how-long-is-the-reset-period-of-the-cpu-bandwith) has been able to [**give a valid answer**](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1220/after-48-hours-cpu-not-reset?rq=1) that applies to all cases.  Also, in the EOS Devs Telegram, there are constantly people commenting that their NET/CPU hasn't come back in over 3 days.  One person today said they've been waiting a week.

This leads me to believe that the recharging process is likely more complex than we realize.

Previously, we thought it might be 24 hours because of what's in the [chain config file](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/libraries/chain/include/eosio/chain/config.hpp#L48); however, that must be a metric for something else.

```
static const uint32_t account_cpu_usage_average_window_ms  = 24*60*60*1000l;
static const uint32_t account_net_usage_average_window_ms  = 24*60*60*1000l;
```

Then we decided it was 3 days because of what EOS NY has on https://www.eosrp.io/

Please post the code where you find the logic to answer this.

---

https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/libraries/chain/resource_limits.cpp
https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/libraries/chain/include/eosio/chain/resource_limits_private.hpp

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is what I understand after a quick walk, through the code.

Your usage status is checked and updated on the chain only when an action​ is done with your account.( This is intuitive, when I look back, because updating all the account usage statuses periodically will be a huge load on the blockchain)

So what you see when you check your usage is the status of your account at the time of your last action. But you ( or your wallet or any front-end) can calculate your current status if the window size, time of the last action etc. are known.

I guess most wallets or front-ends may not be doing this as of now. Which gives seemingly different usage update processes for different users.

Check these files

eos/libraries/chain/include/eosio/chain/resource_limits_private.hpp

eos/libraries/chain/resource_limits.cpp

The 3 day period you mentioned is, used for calculating the exponential moving average and is not the repletion period.

The variable account_cpu_usage_average_window_ms  represents the 24 hour period in milliseconds. This when divided by the block interval (500ms) gives the number of slots in 24 hours, represented by the variable account_cpu_usage_average_window.

This value is later used as the window size. So I understand the repletion period as 24 hours. I haven't checked any of these things in any wallets, so I recommend doing it before making decisions based on the code alone.

In short, 24 hours is the real repletion period, though it may not apparently​ get reflected, in the usage status received from the blockchain.

Comment: That's helpful. Can you share where some or all of that logic is at?  I saw some in the chain config file.

Comment: Added the filenames in the answer

Comment: Updated the specifics of logic

Comment: i just confirmed this! 
I had 300ms of cpu used. But after 3 days my CPU didnt go down. So i just made a TX and the cpu reseted immediately

Answer (score 1):

```
static const uint32_t account_cpu_usage_average_window_ms  = 24*60*60*1000l;
static const uint32_t account_net_usage_average_window_ms  = 24*60*60*1000l;
```

It's **24 hours**.

- 1000ms = 1s
- 1s * 60 = 1m
- 1m * 60 = 1 hr
- 1 hr * 24 = .. 24 hours.