# CPU reset period and CPU used over max amount

Tags: cpu

My problem: I have used more CPU than my max allowed amount. And this is not getting reset despite that one week has passed since I noticed it.

I tried to stake up some EOS (but not enough to reach the total amount needed) as I have read a new transaction is needed to make it recalculate. It did not change anything. So when is it getting reset? Do I indeed need to send a new transaction? But then I need to replenish my CPU first as without CPU, no transaction....

Note: there have been some similar questions asked here

- [After 48 hours, CPU not reset](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1220/after-48-hours-cpu-not-reset)
- [How long is the reset period of the cpu bandwith?](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/912/how-long-is-the-reset-period-of-the-cpu-bandwith)

But none of them seem to answer my question